# Am I using the Symfony flash variables the wrong way?

Tags: php, symfony1

In an action, I set some feedback for the user :

```
    $this->getUser()->setFlash('message', array(
    "type" => "notice",
    "content" => "Well done buddy, you did it."
    ));

    $this->redirect('home/index');
```

In the view, I just use the following code :

```
<?php if ($sf_user->hasFlash('message')): $message = $sf_user->getFlash('message') ?>
  <p class="<?php echo $message["type"] ?>" ><?php echo $message["content"]?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But the message never appears.

Not that the problem is not 'it appears once then it disapears' cause that would mean it works. The problem is that it never appears. Not once.

I'm using Symfony 1.2, this is why flash var are now binded to the user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the same with two `setFlash` with strings (not array). I think this will work. Symfony is escaping arrays when accessing it in the template. try `var_dump($sf_user->getFlash('message'));` to be sure what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Flashes in Symfony are for displaying the response exactly once on a page, i.e. "flash" a message. If the page is refreshed, that flash won't be there anymore.

So assuming the user submitted a form, and the action executed the following code

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash( 'message', 'Some message here' );
```

And the view has the following

```
# Note: getFlash returns "" if flash is not set
echo $sf_user->getFlash('message');
```

Then the very first request from this user to the view after submitting the form, and thus setting that flash would result in getFlash returning "*Some message here*" and removing / unsetting the flash. So any request for the same message from that user will now return an empty string.

What this means is, a flash lasts for only one request. It is a good way to display form responses on the same page as the form.

Comment: I know that flash are ephemerial variables. I didn't mean it work once, then I reloaded the web page and it didn't work. I meant it worked the expected way once, then whole mecanisme didn't work anymore. Maybe I changed soemthing, but I don't feel like it.

Comment: I understand the confusion so I removed the sentence to avoid this answser to be repeated.