# Flashdata not render in view

Tags: twig, session-variables, symfony-2.3

im try print an alert report before a submit form.
The constroller check that entity was valid and inform the result:

```
$estado = Array();
if(count($errors) > 0){
    $estado['alert'] = 'alert-error';
    $estado['message'] = $errors->get(0);
}else{    
    $estado['alert'] = 'alert-success';
    $estado['message'] = "Usuario creado correctamente";
}

$this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('status',$estado);
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('alta_usuario'));
```

So, in the view:

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('status') %}
<div class="alert {{ app.session.get('status').alert }}">   
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{ app.session.get('status').message }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

But Symfony fails with the next message:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("alert") on a NULL variable ("")

In the profiler the Flashdata is:

```
status : [{"alert":"alert-error","message":{}}]
```

Two questions:
1) Why "message" is null ? the entity has an error and `$errors->get(0)` should be get the first error ?
2) Why can't access the `$estado` values from the view ?.

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

This question is much  similar as below link. 
You can find the answer at 
[Am I using the Symfony flash variables the wrong way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926791/am-i-using-the-symfony-flash-variables-the-wrong-way)